# Human detection from video

Tags: algorithm, opencv, video, detection

Can somebody recommend me a software or algorithm in Matlab, c++ with them i can detect people in video sequence? I tried Dalal algorithm, and also OpenCV people detection sample, but it seems to work only for images, and it is not real-time. Dalal wrote in his thesis about motion HOG, but I don't find any realization, algorithm to it.

Comment: Detection of people in arbitrary video is still very much an open area of research.  I'd start here and fan outward based on references : http://www.google.com/search?q=human+detection+video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you won't find it as a software, maybe as a research project. I think OpenCV approach is quite good. Why not to see at the source and improve/optimize it for your needs or platform?

Most algorithms in OpenCV does not use GPU for example. 
They probably use OpenMP or other IBM multithreading library not optimal or not available in your platform.
These are two things you could investigate on ;)

Hope it helps