# OpenCV - detecting a shape in a shape collection (e.g. human in a group of humans)

Tags: image-processing, opencv, image-segmentation, emgucv

I am performing blob extraction from video and using the blob's aspect ratio  to classify into humans or vehicles. Works pretty well since vehicles and humans have quite differentiated aspect ratios.

However this logic breaks down when a group of humans - say mother & child holding hands, or a group walking closely, come by and the blob detection is one single blob.

I am wondering what the best approach to segmenting the image would be. Ideally I would also like to count the humans in the group.

Here are some thoughts:

- canny-> contour-> try the various size of the contours using Hu Moments shape matching?
  The problem is I don't know how many humans are likely to be in this group
- canny->contour> template matching using a template of a human contour. This might work given its general scale invariance.

Any other thoughts on how I should approach this? Thanks for all suggestions and inputs/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Human detection from video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530168/human-detection-from-video)

Comment: @karlphilip, this is not a dupe. The question was about using HOG , my idea is shape/contour based comparison.

Comment: You are right, I should have chosed either "not a real question" or "too localized".

Comment: hmm..disagree with that as well.

Comment: @Mikos If the people are holding hands, then when you analyze the blob contour as a 1D curve (after some given shape signature transformation), you might find relevant regional minima to separate the people.

Comment: @Mikos This question is better suited to [OpenCV answers](http://answers.opencv.org).

Comment: @karlphillip huh ? I don't see the point in restricting this to opencv, the method doesn't matter on the toolkit used.

Comment: Gentlemen, this question is about **computer vision not programming**. Computer vision is a big research field within computer science. I believe this alone makes the question  *too localized* or *off topic*. There's no code involved and it's not programming related. This should be moved to our sister site, [Digital Signal Processing](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @karlphillip I'm not sure why you want to close this question so badly, the same can be said about basically any question tagged as such in this site. The answers given here can easily involve code.

Comment: @karlphillip - I feel you are make a distinction without a difference. What about algorithmic questions on this site, often not code related - are they "programming related"?. My question is algorithmic, so would appreciate if you did not take this stand/

Comment: @mmgp - could you clarify your response a bit? Would your approach work when the overlaps between humans is variable (as it usually is)?

Comment: @Mikos i'm not sure what part of it is unclear, what is your actual doubt ? If you can include some actual and /representative/ examples for the situations you have, I can try to include a proper answer.

Comment: Anyone with a CS degree (or experience in programming) can answer algorithmic questions, but these same people cannot answer **computer vision** questions, because that takes a lot more than programming experience. If your question was about some bug/problem in a code, or a question related to OpenCV API, etc, etc, it would be OK. However, you question demands much more than that to be answered. Anyway, I feel like we've discussed this so many times in the past few years that doing it again is a bit redundant. Forgive me if I disagree with you. Good luck, though.